# Moving records between worksheets when input form value updates

Tags: excel, vba

I am unable to figure out how to cut and paste records between two worksheets when a value from the input form is changed from "Open Project" to "Closed Project."

This is for a project management database I am creating to to cut down the time spent adding new data. So far this is my only time working with VBA.

```
Option explicit    
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 'Searches for record, and cuts/ pastes records into Project Log when Project Status is set to Closed

Dim ab As Worksheet
Dim aa As Worksheet
  Set ab = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Projects No SLA - Log")
  Set aa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Log")
  Dim q As Long
  Dim m As Long

    If Me.proj_stat_combo.Value = "OPEN PROJECTS (No Current Open SLA)" Then
       q = Application.Match(VBA.CLng(Me.srnew_combo.Value), ab.Range("C:C"), 0)
       m = ab.Range("C" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        

    Worksheets("Open Projects No SLA - Log").Range(1).Cut Worksheets("Project Log").Range(m + 1)

  End If
```

Hoping to get the records from "Open Projects No SLA - Log" to be cut out of the worksheet and pasted into the "Project Log" worksheet" when the input form data for Project Status has changed from "OPEN PROJECTS (No Current Open SLA)" to closed.

Comment: What is `q` for here?  What is `ac` ?  please add `Option explicit` at the top of your code module, fix any errors, then re-post your code.

Comment: @TimWilliams q is the variable used to search for the project ID in "Open Projects No SLA - Log." AC is supposed to be AB (fixed) which is referring to "Project Log" Code should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Option explicit    

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 'Searches for record, and cuts/ pastes records into Project Log 
 '     when Project Status is set to Closed

    Dim ab As Worksheet, q As variant, m As Long
    Dim aa As Worksheet

    Set ab = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Projects No SLA - Log")
    Set aa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Log")

    If Me.proj_stat_combo.Value = "OPEN PROJECTS (No Current Open SLA)" Then

       q = Application.Match(VBA.CLng(Me.srnew_combo.Value), ab.Range("C:C"), 0)
       'check we got a match
       If not iserror(q) then
           'adjust next line to fit your # of columns and exact paste destination...
           ab.Cells(q,"A").Resize(1,30).cut aa.Cells(rows.count,"C").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0)
       Else
           Msgbox "No match for project id!"
       End if


  End If
```